# NSScrollView with AutoLayout constrains made window unresponsive to resizing and dragging

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, nswindow, nsscrollview

In [Apple's official Exhibition app demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Exhibition/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016178), there's such usage in `viewDidLoad()` in the `ImageViewerController.swift`

```
/*
    Turn on translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints, Interface Builder
    turns this off for all views in a nib. The `NSScrollView` and `NSClipView` 
    expect to be able to control their documentView via modifying its `frame`.
*/
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

I noticed that in the `xib` file, the `imageView` already has constrains set up. When the line of code is commented out, the view still works.

To better understand the code from the demo, I created a minimal project with only a `NSScrollView` added under the default view controller's view. Here the `NSImageView` is created programmatically. **If the constrains in `h` and `v` are activated, the window will be very big and unresponsive to resizing and dragging.**

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var clipView: NSClipView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Snow.jpg"
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: false)

        let image = NSImage(contentsOf: url)

        let imageView = NSImageView(image: image!)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        clipView.addSubview(imageView)

        let h = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "H:|[imageView]|",
            options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
            metrics: nil,
            views: ["imageView" : imageView])

        let v = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|[imageView]|",
            options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
            metrics: nil,
            views: ["imageView" : imageView])

        clipView.documentView = imageView

        // NSLayoutConstraint.activate([h, v].flatMap({$0}))
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why and how do the constrains in my project cause the problem, while the constrains in the demo don't.
2. Are the constrains in the official demo necessary?

Comment: To make your code work: don't use `clipView`, don't add contraints and add the image view to the scroll view with `scrollView.documentView = imageView`.

Comment: Thanks Willeke! You are right, but in the [Exhibition demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Exhibition/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016178) it uses a `NSClipView` subclass and made the `NSImageView` its `documentView` (by connecting them in the `xib`). It also has the constrains. I'm more interested in the "theory" behind the problem.

Comment: From the documentation of `NSClipView.documentView`: "If the clip view is contained in an NSScrollView, you should send the NSScrollView a documentView message instead …". The scroll view will set `documentView` of the clip view.

Comment: Explore the `NSClipView` subclass `CenteringClipView`. It overrides `constrainBoundsRect`.

Comment: What may cause my window's unresponsiveness (if I do activate the constrains , when I shouldn't but the demo does)? I tried commenting out all the code in `CenteringClipView`, its window is still reponsive to dragging etc.

Comment: The constrains of the `NSImageView` in the Exhibition demo app seem redundant.

Comment: The magic number is 500. Windows resize with a constraint priority of 500. If  horizontal constraints of a layout results in a constraint with a priority of 501 or higher, the window's width will be fixed (not resizable). Ditto for vertical constraints. So, as an example, if I create a simple image view with a width=300@1000 constraint, then pin it to the edges of the window's content view, the window will have a fixed, 300px (content) width. If I set a height=300@250 constraint, the window's vertical resizing (500) will override the height constraint (250) and allow it to resize (vertically).

Comment: @JamesBucanek Thank you! Setting `imageView`’s compression resistance priority did the trick. BTW could you share how you got such profound knowledge of the framework?

Comment: I first remember hearing about this in the [Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/228/) video form WWDC 2012. Eventually I discovered that this is (obscurely and obliquely) documented in the `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut` constant.